# 12th Man in 2019 Ashes

Tags: rules, cricket

I see the 12th man was used in the Ashes today and he was allowed to bat for Australia.  I have read the rules and this is not right according to the Rules. Has something been changed within the past few days.

Answer (score 3):

I presume this is in relation to the use of Marnus Labuschagne as a substitute batsman for Steve Smith during the [second test of the 2019 Ashes series at Lords](https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19430/game/1152847/england-vs-australia-2nd-test-icc-world-test-championship-2019-2021). In which case this is an example of a **Concussion Substitute**.

The concussion substitute was introduced by the ICC to all forms of international cricket (Men's and Women's), and also to First-class cricket, from August 1st 2019 (the start of the new ICC World Test Championship).

It is designed to allow a team to make a "like-for-like" replacement (who can bat and/or bowl), that has been approved by the match referee, for a player that has been forced to retire because of concussion.

The rule can be found within section 1.2 of the ICC Playing Conditions:

> **1.2.7**
>
> If a player sustains a concussion or suspected concussion as a result of a head or neck injury during the course of the relevant
>   match, a Concussion Replacement may be permitted in the following circumstances:
>
> - *1.2.7.1* - the head or neck injury must have been sustained during play and within the playing area described in clause 1.2.5.2
>     above
> - *1.2.7.4* - The Concussion Replacement Request must be submitted within 36 hours of the incident specified in 1.2.7.3.2 if a
>     Concussion Replacement is to be permitted
>
> **1.2.8**
>
> The ICC Match Referee should ordinarily approve a Concussion Replacement Request if the replacement is a like-for-like player
>   whose inclusion will not excessively advantage his team for the remainder of the match
>
> **1.2.10**
>
> Once the Concussion Replacement has been approved by the ICC Match Referee, the replaced player shall play no further part in
>   the match

Above can also be found in the [ICC Guidance Notes](https://icc-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2019/07/31/831e5846-f519-47ca-9fd9-a7a8db375627/WTC-Concussion-Replacement.pdf)

Comment: Strictly, concussion substitutes are not in "all firms of cricket", only ICC controlled international matches.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - have updated to better explain this, but it is also applicable in first-class cricket, too.

Comment: Thankyou very much for that.  Now understood.

Comment: @SueCobb - no problem :) - if you could also click the little tick next to my answer - this will mark my answer as the 'accepted answer', making it easier for future readers to find the right answer.